# Nestjs exclude path for middleware

Tags: express, nestjs

I'd like to apply `MyMiddleware` for all routes (eg. `/foo`, `/bar`) but not for  `/`

Following config doesn't work, because it applies middleware also to `/`

```
@Module({
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export default class AppModule implements NestModule {

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(MyMiddleware).exclude('/').forRoutes('/*');
  }

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I solved in my own.

I misunderstood this doc paragraph:

> The characters ?, +, *, and () may be used in a route path, and are subsets of their regular expression counterparts. The hyphen ( -) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally by string-based paths

I found that the syntax is the same of expressJs that links to https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp.

I've used this useful tool http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ to figure out the regex applied behind the scenes

The solution to my case is simply:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [MyController],
})
export default class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(MyMiddleware).forRoutes('/[a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+');
  }
}
```